# Pattern rule with pattern that occurs in directory and library

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have some libraries that I need as prerequisites for a target, and those libraries are stored in directories that contain the library name:

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- a
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- lib-a
|-- b
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- lib-a
`-- out
```

where `out` requires both `a/lib-a` and `b/lib-b`. Both libs can be built by simply entering the directory and executing `make lib-<X>` there.

My idea of a `Makefile` with a pattern rule to avoid repetitions was this, which would have worked if both files were in the same directory or in different directories but with the same name, ie. I had needed to use `%` only once:

```
all: out

out: a/lib-a b/lib-b
    cat $^ > out

%/lib-%:
    make -C $(dir $@)
```

This doesn't work, however, since the `%/lib-%` pattern is illegal.

Comment: You could put the recipe in a canned recipe to avoid duplicating the recipe contents or you could build up the targets using `foreach`, `call`, etc. to avoid duplication that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use the raw `make` command when invoking a sub-make.  Always use `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}`) variables.

In short there is no way to write a pattern rule where multiple patterns are required.

If they all have the same recipe then the simplest thing to do is construct the target list and write them all in a single rule:

```
TARGETS := a b

all: out

OUT_TARGETS := $(foreach T,$(TARGETS),$T/lib-$T)

out: $(OUT_TARGETS)

$(OUT_TARGETS):
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D)

.PHONY: all out $(OUT_TARGETS)
```